# Using Wget on a google drive file

Tags: unix, wget

https://drive.google.com/a/uci.edu/uc?export=download&confirm=LJ_a&id=0Bxy-54SBqeekTlE4Qy1mWWpsYTQ

I am attempting to use Wget to download the file above. However, it only generates 1 KB log file. I enter:

```
    wget https://drive.google.com/a/uci.edu/uc?export=download&confirm=a-GD&id=0Bxy-54SBqeekTlE4Qy1mWWpsYTQ
```

However, this gives me a log file instead of actually downloading the file.

The file size is 13 GB tar. The log file looks like this:

```
    --2017-11-14 13:59:32--  https://drive.google.com/a/uci.edu/uc export=download 
    Resolving drive.google.com (drive.google.com)... [IP ADDRESS GIVEN]
    Connecting to drive.google.com (drive.google.com)|[IP ADDRESS GIVEN]... connected.
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 400 Bad Request
    2017-11-14 13:59:33 ERROR 400: Bad Request.
```

Comment: It is found that from file ID, the file you want to download is not Google Docs. Can I ask you about the size of file? And can you show us the log? Of course, please remove private information. If you can do, please add them to your question. The additional information will be helpful for other users to think of the solution.

Comment: I added the information

Comment: Is this answer useful for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45495986/end-of-central-directory-signature-not-found/45496424#45496424

Comment: Its unclear to me how exactly it relates

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't be helpful for you.

Answer (score 9):

1. Open download link in the browser with incognito mode. Proceed normally as you would to download that file.
2. Click "Download" button. When download starts in the browser, pause it and copy the download link.
3. At command prompt, do

   wget *copied_link*

It should work for any file. or you can directly download your file from [here](https://doc-10-as-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ha0ro937gcuc7l7deffksulhg5h7mbp1/h73akkbj80m5gk2gurt3bqi1es52ckva/1513166400000/00505303766612474388/*/0Bxy-54SBqeekTlE4Qy1mWWpsYTQ?e=download)