# Why `unzip protoc-21.4-osx-universal_binary.zip` fails when handling files downloaded with curl

Tags: macos, curl, unzip

I'm learning about how to use gRPC with GOLANG on a Macbook Pro/ macOS Big Sur / 11.6.8, using the instructions on the [Protocol Buffer Compiler Installation](https://grpc.io/docs/protoc-installation/) page, where it instructs the reader to use `curl` to download the `protoc` compiler archive, and `unzip` to expand the archive. I'm executing the following command sequence:

```
curl -LO https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/protoc-21.4-osx-universal_binary.zip
unzip protoc-21.4-osx-universal_binary.zip -d /Users/rodrigosilveira/.local
```

The unzip execution fails, with the following message:

```
Archive:  protoc-21.4-osx-universal_binary.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of protoc-21.4-osx-universal_binary.zip or
        protoc-21.4-osx-universal_binary.zip.zip, and cannot find protoc-21.4-osx-universal_binary.zip.ZIP, period.
```

**DEBUG NOTES**:

***Unzip works without using curl***

- visit the [Protocol Buffers v21.4](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases) page
- double click the `protoc-21.4-osx-universal_binary.zip` file,
- `unzip` to expand the `protoc-21.4-osx-universal_binary.zip` archive in my local `Downloads` folder

***Existing SO answers do not help***

- [Unziping zipped file in google colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59145199/unziping-zipped-file-in-google-colab)
- [Using cURL to upload POST data with files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667797/using-curl-to-upload-post-data-with-files)
- [End-of-central-directory signature not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45495986/end-of-central-directory-signature-not-found)
- [can't download github project with curl command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261100/cant-download-github-project-with-curl-command)

Comment: unzip is complaining because you haven't downloaded the zip file at all. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25923939/how-do-i-download-binary-files-of-a-github-release for details of downloading github assets

Comment: Ouch, a total debugging blindspot on my part, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The current URL for this utility is

```
https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v21.5/protoc-21.5-osx-universal_binary.zip
```

The previous one return "Not found" and this is the reason you get this `zip` error